# Swift (String:AnyObject) is not convertible to [String:AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I got a code like this but the Xcode show an error:

> (String:AnyObject) is not convertible to [String:AnyObject]

```
func personDetails (dic : [String:AnyObject]) -> Array<Person> {
       for personDic: [String : AnyObject] in dict { >> error in this line
        let person = Person.init(person: personDic)
        //rest the code
        }
}
```

How to make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is probably following:

```
for (key, value) in dict {
    let person = Person(person: [key: value])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, you trying iterate for loop and in `for loop` you want every iteration to be a `Dictionary` from a `Dictionary` that is not possible. You can write for loop with Dictionary like this.

```
for(key,value) in dict {
    print(key)
    print(value)
}
```

Here key contain key and value contains its corresponding value for that key. Using this loop you can iterate to every `key->value` pair of dictionary.